# Ignore Special Characters from Expose Filter

Tags: views

How I can ignore special characters from expose filter.for example: I have a view with expose filter ( Title ) but if I write the text without special characters it returns ( No Result ) & if write the text with those special characters I have resulted.

Note: When I created the node I wrote the Title with special characters

Example: I created a node with Title (i'ts)
if I searched in expose filter by using (its) it returns(No Result) but if I wrote (i'ts) it works fine

Answer (score 0):

in hook_form_alter function you can check the expose form and write your below function.

function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}

assign value to form value array.

Comment: unfortunately did not work, do you have another way to solve this problem?